# Understanding a step in this proof by induction

Tags: inequality, induction

Here's an example I discovered in a book.

> Prove inequality when $a\ge-1$:$$(1 + a)^n \ge 1 + na.$$
>
> Let's use mathematical induction. Then $n = 1$ left and right parts are equals.
>
> Let's suppose statemant is right when $n = k.$ Multiply on $(1 + a)$: $$(1 + a)^{k + 1}\ge (1 + ka)(1 + a)\\(1 + a)^{k + 1} \ge 1 + (k + 1)a + ka^2$$
>
> Removing $ka^2$ as non-negative in right part of equation get: $$(1 + a)^{k + 1} \ge 1 + (k + 1)a$$ Inequality is proved.

I don't understand: why they can remove $ka^2$ in right part of equation?

Comment: "Removing" isn't really descriptive of what happens. Rather they use the transitivity of $\ge $ (which says that if $x\ge y$ and $y\ge z$, then $x\ge z$, for all $x,y,z\in \mathbb R$). They use the fact that $1+(k+1)a+ka^2\ge 1+(k+1)a$.

Comment: since $ka^2>0$, therefore $1+(k+1)a+ka^2 \geq  1+(k+1)a$. Now use the fact that $A \geq B$ and $B \geq C$, then $A \geq C$.

Comment: Or, if you want to think of it as "removing," consider that the left side is already bigger than the right side.  Removing something positive (since $k > 0$ and $a^2$ is always positive) from the right side only makes the left side biggerer than it was before.

Comment: Gosh, what a crazy formatting! You should only write formulas in MathJax...

Comment: What editor do you use? I tried write mannually. Now i write in MathType for Windows

Answer (score 1):

The author is leaving out (arguably tedious) steps. This may be because the author thinks they are obvious, and so not worth mentioning. This may be because the author thinks they are not too far from obvious, and so leaves the additional steps as an understanding-enhancement exercise for the reader.

Note that $k$ is positive and $a^2\ge0.$ (Do you see why both of these claims are true?) Hence, since $$0\le a^2,$$ then by positivity of $k$ we have $$k\cdot 0\le k\cdot a^2,$$ which can be rewritten as $$0\le ka^2.\tag{1}$$ (With me so far?) Now, adding $1+(k+1)a$ to both sides of $(1)$, we have $$1+(k+1)a\le 1+(k+1)a+ka^2,$$ which can be rewritten as $$1+(k+1)a\le (1+ka)(1+a).\tag{2}$$ Now, since $-1\le a,$ then $0\le 1+a.$ From this, and the assumption that $$1+ka\le(1+a)^k,$$ we can conclude that $$(1+ka)(1+a)\le(1+a)^k(1+a),$$ which can be rewritten as $$(1+ka)(1+a)\le(1+a)^{k+1}\tag{3}.$$ (Still with me?) Finally, from $(2)$ and $(3),$ we conclude that $$1+(k+1)a\le(1+a)^{k+1},\tag{$\heartsuit$}$$ as desired.

If you have trouble justifying any of these steps (or even if you just want to bounce proof attempts off of somebody), feel free to leave a comment, and I will reply as soon as I am able.